# SQL Server calling remote stored procedure in trigger from linked server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a database called `IND_DB` (running on SQL Server 2008 R2) which has a table called `MyTable`. When there is any update in `MyTable`, a trigger is fired. The trigger updates another table called `RemoteTable` located on another server (SQL Server 2008 R2) & database. The trigger calls a stored procedure located on the remote server and updates a table on the remote server.

In order to accomplish this I have created a linked server between two servers. I have set the following properties of the link server:

- RPC: TRUE
- RPC OUT: TRUE

I have confirmed the MSDTC is running in both server. The firewall is not blocking the transaction.

Now when the trigger is fired, following error is shown:

> No Row Updated.
>
> The data in row 1 was not committed.
>
> Error Source: .NET SQLClient Data Provider.
>
> Error Message: Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The problem is that I can execute remote stored procedure in a query analyzer but the same remote stored procedure won't run in trigger.